# Rails or my SMTP client Gmail, does not allow large CSV file attachments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, gmail, mime-types, actionmailer

I'm trying to have ActionMailer deliver a CSV I generated as so :

```
@csv= CSV.generate(force_quotes: true) do |csv|
  ::CourseExportGenerator.load_template csv, sections, standard, registration
end   

@filename = "my_sweet_filename.csv"
EnterpriseMailer.send_report(@csv, @filename).deliver
```

Then my EnterpriseMailer.rb file looks like so :

```
def send_report report, filename
  attachments["#{filename}"] = {data: report, encoding: 'base64'}
  mail to: 'trip@triptrip.com', subject: "Your large CSV file!"
end
```

The email gets delivered with the right subject, but none of my actual content ( which is just some simple placeholder text). The file attached is titled "noname" and when it's opened it reads :

```
This is a multi-part message in MIME format...

----
```

I know the file it's delivering is roughly 2 to 3 megabytes and have over 8,000 lines.

Does anyone know how I can send simply deliver a large CSV file within an email attachment? Maybe I'm writing the syntax incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that I had to create this file *within* the Mailer itself. Not sure why that works, but it does.

My enterprise_mailer.rb looks like this :

```
attachments["#{@filename}"] = CSV.generate(force_quotes: true) do |csv|
  ::ExportGenerator.load_template csv, sections, standard, registration
end
mail to: 'trip@triptrip.com', subject: "My totally awesome subject line"
```